# Probability of a point taken from a certain normal distribution will be less than or equal to than a point taken from another?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, python, scipy, numpy

Suppose we have two independent normal distributions
[image]

How do I calculate the probability of a certain point taken from distribution X1 being `less than or equal to` a certain point taken from distribution X2 in Python?

With reference to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40224/probability-of-a-point-taken-from-a-certain-normal-distribution-will-be-greater) I can say that the formula for `greater than` could be something like this,

Example,

```
m1, std1 = 1, 2 
m2, std2 = 2, 3

#then,
```

[image]

and,
[image]

```
# hence, 
from scipy.stats import norm
p = 1 - norm.cdf(-(m1 - m2) / np.sqrt(std1 + std2))
```

I am looking for the [image]

We are looking for the probability of a point taken from a blue distribution such that it's less than a point taken from the orange distribution.

[image]

Comment: you get the formula in your equations, unless I'm missing something $P(X_1 - X_2 \le 0) = P(X_1 \le X_2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $P(X_1\leq X_2)=1-P(X_1>X_2)$, using your formula, it’ll be $\Phi(-\mu/\sigma)$.